# How to export a Vue component in word format?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, vue-component

I have a vue template that looks like this-

```html
<template>
  <div id="printContainer">
    <componentA></componentA>
    <div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
    <componentB></componentB>
    <div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
    <componentC></componentC>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want to download the "printContainer" `div`'s HTML.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template ref to access the `printContainer` `<div>` from code:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const printContainer = ref()
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="printContainer">
    <!-- your components here -->
  </div>
</template>
```

and then get its `innerHTML`. For example, you could have a button that logs the container's `innerHTML` when clicked:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const printContainer = ref()

const logContents = () => {
  console.log('contents', printContainer.value.innerHTML)
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="logContents">Log contents</button>
  ⋮
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-get-rendered-html-of-container?file=src%2FApp.vue)